# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'subreddit' Discord.PY

Tags: python, discord.py, praw

```
@client.command()
async def reddit(ctx):
    memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit('memes').hot()
    post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 10)
    for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
        submission = next(x for x in memes_submissions if not x.stickied)

    await ctx.send(submission.url)
```

This is my code. When I type `.reddit` it should find a random hot meme from r/memes. Instead of giving me some fresh memes, It gives me an error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'subreddit'
```

As I understand the program doesn't know what subreddit is. But I think it should get the subreddit command from PRAW. This is how I defined `reddit`:

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id="id",
                 client_secret="secret",
                 user_agent="MASTERBOT")
```

I'm thinking that It might be because of me writing or defining the `user_agent` wrong because I have no idea what that does. I have everything imported as they should be. In everyone the code seems working. Might It be a preblem with my Python? I am running it on 3.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same issue happened again with your namespace - you called your command `reddit` even though you already created your `reddit` variable outside of the command.

Try renaming it:

```py
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id="id", ....)

@client.command(name="reddit") # this is what the command will be in discord
async def _reddit(ctx):
    memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit('memes').hot()
    post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 10)
    for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
        submission = next(x for x in memes_submissions if not x.stickied)

    await ctx.send(submission.url)
```

---

You've already got your variable `reddit` defined here:

```py
reddit = praw.Reddit(...)
```

So having a function defined like so:

```py
async def reddit(...):
```

will shadow the variable you defined outside, and if you try to refer to `reddit` within the function, it'll actually be looking at `async def reddit(...):` instead of `reddit = praw.Reddit(...)`, as it's the most recent definition of the variable.

Comment: I can see that you answer all my questions. First I want to thank you for that. I'm getting the error:   Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'url'
C:\Users\emirs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\events.py:81: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited
  self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: @Mr.Beanos.- Would you mind adding `print(locals()["submission"])` just above your `await ctx.send(submission.url)` line, and see what it says?

Comment: It prints this:  <coroutine object Command.__call__ at 0x0F8887A8>

Comment: Hm, okay. And how about `print(locals()["submissions"])`?

Comment: It doesn't say anything. It gives me an KeyError.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215329/discussion-between-diggy-and-mr-beanos).

Comment: Yeah, but I have a command called work, but there's no other variable in the python script called work.